# Bash string comparasion does not work as expected

Tags: bash

I use this bash code to test whether two strings are equal, but the result is not as what I exptect. I have used `""` to wrap two strings and used `[[]]` rather than `[]` in `if` condition, but still failed. Where did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
touch a.txt b.txt
date -r a.txt +%y-%m-%d > b.txt
A="$(cat b.txt)"
B="$(date -r a.txt +%y-%m-%d)"
if [["$A" == "$B"]]
then
  echo "equal"
else
  echo "not equal"
fi
```

Error is listed below.

```bash
➜  ~ chmod a+x test.sh
➜  ~ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 6: [[22-10-13: command not found
not equal
```

Comment: check your script with shellcheck

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a space between `[[` and `"$A"` and between `"$B"` and `]]`.

This is because in bash, `[`, `]`, `[[` and `]]` are commands:

```bash
$ type [
[ is a builtin
```

Weird right?

Comment: Even more surprisingly, one gets `[ is a shell builtin`, but `[[ is a shell keyword`. The former is perhaps a “legacy” matter related to `/usr/bin/[` and standard POSIX shells whereas the latter is closer to what this construct “should be” in Bash.

Comment: Please don't answer simple typo questions. Just leave a comment and vote to close.

Comment: @tripleee, in my opinion, this is not a typo, this comes from misunderstanding what brackets are in shell. And that means that an explanation is worth the trouble...

Comment: Yeah, but we already have a canonical for that, so please vote to close as a duplicate. The [`bash` tag info page](/tags/bash/info) has a list of common FAQs.

Comment: That being said, I see that this question is a duplicate, which is a good argument for closing